# Stored Procedures and SSRS 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 that consists of multple select statements.  When building a report in SSRS, I have a dataset that uses that stored procedure.  However, the only fields that show up are the ones that are in the first select statement.  Is there a way to show the other fields or use multiple select statements within one stored procedure?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the selects output the same schema (i.e. fields)? If so, and if you need all the results, you could try UNIONing the separate queries together. Otherwise, why not move the query you need into a new stored proc and call that from the report?

Comment: And BTW if you split out the query in question into a new proc but need to preserve the initial proc as is, you could always call the new proc from the old proc instead of having that SQL block in two places.

Answer (score 1):

Eric, it's been my experience that when SSRS is based on a stored procdure, the results of the ***last*** Select statement are used and not the first. So you should be able to do anything you want up until the last Select statement in the stored proc and then make sure the last Select contains the correct data/columns for the report.

Answer (score 1):

From the MSDN [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239331.aspx)

> If multiple result sets are retrieved
>   through a single query, only the first
>   result set is processed, and all other
>   result sets are ignored. For example,
>   when you run the following query in
>   the text-based query designer, only
>   the result set for Production.Product
>   appears in the result pane:

```
SELECT ProductID FROM Production.Product
GO
SELECT ContactID FROM Person.Contact
```